# Bluetooth headset gets paired on Kubuntu 18.04 but never gets reconnected

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth

I have a set of "House of Marley EM-JE083-SB" wireless earphones with mic, which I am trying to connect it to my Kubuntu 18.04.

I am able to pair it and keep using it fine. But if I disconnect the headphones and then try to connect it again, it doesn't show up in the systemtray.

[image: Bluetooth systray empty]

If I go into bluetooth settings and then try to connect to the headphone manually, it tries to connect for a while and then fails without any feedback.

[image: Bluetooth settings]

If I remove the pairing entirely, and then do a fresh pairing, then I am able to use it again properly.

What could be the reason the headset is not reconnecting properly? How do I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved in a recent update.